# System.Text.Json.deserialize Json String

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I have a question about `System.Text.Json.deserialize`.
I have got the Json value like this

```json
    {
        "id" :"1",
        "ShopName" :"Paint Shop",
        "Books" : [1,2]
    }
```

It can easy convert to simple object as

```cs
    public class bookstore {
        public int id {get;set}
        public string ShopName {get;set}
        public IEnumerable<int> Books {get;set}
    }
```

But I have a function which convert books array int into list of object like this

```json
    {
        "id" :"1",
        "ShopName" :"Paint Shop",
        "Books" : [
            {
                "bookId":1,
                "bookName":"Peter Pan",
                "location":"A01"
            },
            {
                "bookId":2,
                "bookName":"Cooking Book",
                "location":"A02"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Right now, I want to modify the value of `Books[1].location` value, by using `jsonnode.parse(string)` to convert the object.
Can I know how to do it ?

Thank you

Comment: This looks wrong: `public IEnumerable<int> Books {get;set}` It should be `public IEnumerable<Book> Books {get;set}` where `Book`  is a class containing book properties.

Comment: Once you have that, you can deserialize everything and access the `location` property of the books.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know why you want to use the `JsonNode.Parse()`.

If you just want to modify the `location`'s value, maybe you can use the `JsonSerializer` with `BookStore` and `Book` class to help you.
 The `Book` class is a `IEnumerable` property of `BookStore`.

an example by `.NET6 Console App`
 `BookClass` is a **2-level nested** class

```cs
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System.Text.Json;

// Initialize json string
string jsonStr = "{\"id\": 1, \"ShopName\" :\"Paint Shop\", \"Books\" : [\r\n            {\r\n                \"bookId\":1,\r\n                \"bookName\":\"Peter Pan\",\r\n                \"location\":\"A01\"\r\n            },\r\n            {\r\n                \"bookId\":2,\r\n                \"bookName\":\"Cooking Book\",\r\n                \"location\":\"A02\"\r\n            }\r\n        ]\r\n    }";

// Deserilize to object
Bookstore bookstore = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Bookstore>(jsonStr);

// Write the location's value
Console.WriteLine(bookstore.Books.ToArray()[1].location);

// Modified the location's value
bookstore.Books.ToArray()[1].location += "_Modified";

// Write the modified location's value
Console.WriteLine(bookstore.Books.ToArray()[1].location);

// See result output
Console.ReadLine();

public class Bookstore
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string ShopName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int bookId { get; set; }
    public string bookName { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
}
```

Result output image
[image]

---

If you persist to use `JsonNode.Parse()`, then need more steps. like this.

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

// Initialize json string
string jsonStr = "{\"id\": 1, \"ShopName\" :\"Paint Shop\", \"Books\" : [\r\n            {\r\n                \"bookId\":1,\r\n                \"bookName\":\"Peter Pan\",\r\n                \"location\":\"A01\"\r\n            },\r\n            {\r\n                \"bookId\":2,\r\n                \"bookName\":\"Cooking Book\",\r\n                \"location\":\"A02\"\r\n            }\r\n        ]\r\n    }";

// Parse to jsonNode
JsonNode jsonNode = JsonNode.Parse(jsonStr);

// Convert to JsonObject
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonNode.AsObject();

// Convert Books to Json Array
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Books"].AsArray();

// Convert index 1 in array to Json object
JsonObject book1Object = jsonArray[1].AsObject();

// Write the location value 
Console.WriteLine(book1Object["location"]);

// Modify location value 
book1Object["location"] += "_modified";

// Write the modified location value 
Console.WriteLine(book1Object["location"]);

// See output
Console.ReadLine();

public class Bookstore
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string ShopName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int bookId { get; set; }
    public string bookName { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
}
```

---

#### Other suggestion

Use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.2-beta2) is better. Because when convert a json to a C# object, will need to convert many properties with different value type.
The [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.2-beta2) had already handle these situation, at the mean time the `System.Text.Json` does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JObject` to modify json directly

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

jObject["Books"][1]["location"] = "new value";
```

Result:

[image]

**Note:**

You should add `Newtonsoft.Json` package.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using System.Text.Json, you can change value using this code

```
var jsonParsed=JsonNode.Parse(json);
jsonParsed["Books"][1]["location"]="A03";
```

after this , if you need you can get an updated json

```
json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonParsed, new JsonSerializerOptions {WriteIndented=true});
```